# Returns HTTP 500 code when accessing resource using HTTPS

Tags: java, rest, https, jersey-client

I wrote a sample Java REST Client application to access a resource, but it gives the 500 error. Here resource can be accessed through HTTPS only.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target("https://<location>").path("<path>");

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
        formData.add("Amount", "100.00");
        formData.add("Currency", "NZD");
        formData.add("EmailAddress", "test@gmail.com");

        Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(Entity.form(formData));
```

When i invoked the request from Web Browser, it works fine.

What is the problem with my code? 
Since Protocol "HTTPS" requires some additional configurations?

Comment: You need to examine the server-side logs to discover what went wrong. HTTP response code 500 is deliberately designed not to leak information to the client.

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately, I don't have access to it. It is a Testing Payment Gateway server which is managed by a separate team.

Comment: So ask that team. Nothing further you can accomplish until then.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.bhaveshthaker.com/24/calling-invoking-secure-restful-web-service-over-https-with-jax-rs-in-java-without-keystore-truststore-information/

For your reference..

Yes, HTTP and HTTPS cannot be used interchangeably. You need different client configuration for same if your server code is using SSL certificate/ user created certificate.

Comment: If he got any kind of HTTP response code at all it is an indication that the HTTPS part is working perfectly.

Comment: It simply means your server code has some kind of security enabled . Client code should handle that.

Comment: It means that the server encountered some failure about which there is exactly zero information available to the client. A security failure might result in HTTP 401, 403, 407, ... for example. Your answer remains incorrect.